# Log-linear analysis in Excel

Tags: excel, log-linear

Is it possible to conduct a log-linear analysis in Excel? Is a log-linear analysis (as defined in SPSS) the same as a log-linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple definitions of the term log-linear analysis. I would use for a type of analysis that is like ANOVA for categorical dependent variables. Others (economists) use the term for first log transforming a dependent variable and than perform a linear regression on the transformed variable.

I don't use Excel for statistical analysis, and I recommend you don't either. It is just not a statistical analysis package, and it is thus not optimised for it. There used to be huge problems with it, I have heard it has become a bit better, but I would still not trust it in the same way I would trust results from programs specifically designed for performing statistical analyses.

Having said all that, if Excel can perform a Poisson regression, than you can trick it into doing a log-linear analysis of the first kind. I know you can do a log transformation and linear regression, so you can also do a log-linear analysis of the second kind.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is Turing complete, so you can do pretty much anything. Not that you necessarily should.

That said, I've indulged in quick and dirty statistical models in Excel, and the most straightforward way to build them is generally to to use the solver's add-in to fit the parameters to minimize the square error of your prediction, or to find a maximum likelihood estimate of parameters.